# Mysql Events Execution Start time

Tags: mysql, events

I have one mysql event which will execute every 1 day and do some activity. Please find code snippets for the same.

```
delimiter |    
CREATE EVENT createTest     
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
DO
BEGIN
  -- Do some work
END |
delimiter ;
```

when i created this event it executes same time for the same day. For next day it executes (last execution + 24 Hour) scenario.

is it possible to set start time in events? I want to executes this events on every day 0 hour?

Comment: I am using Mysql 5.5 on windows server 2008 r2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. Use STARTS option for this purpose.

```
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY
STARTS '2012-10-03 00:00:00'
DO 
BEGIN
 -- do something
END
```

Note, that event start datetime must be in a future.

---

For @spt -

```
CREATE EVENT event1
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' YEAR
    STARTS '2016-04-01 00:00:00'
    DO 
BEGIN
END
```

Also, if it is hard to create and setup event object, you can use GUI event object editor in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (free Express edition allows it).

Comment: Note that at least with MySQL 5.6 (can't say with earlier versions), a start time in the past works just fine!

Comment: HOW to schedule a event at every year on april 1 at 00:00:00

Comment: CREATE EVENT s
    ON SCHEDULE AT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-04-01 00:00:00') as DATE)
    DO 
BEGIN 
UPDATE medical.medtest SET BALANCE = 1;
UPDATE medical.medtest 
SET 
    HOS_1 = 1;
END I have tried this

Answer (score 7):

You can use this:

```
CREATE EVENT createTest     
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY
STARTS CONCAT(DATE(NOW()+INTERVAL 1 DAY ), ' 00:00:00')
DO 
BEGIN
 -- do your task
END
```