# mySQL delete event every 30 seconds

Tags: mysql, events

I need to add a mySQL event which deletes data every 30 seconds but only if the server time seconds are equal 0 or 30, HH:MM:00 or HH:MM:30.

How can i chage my event to do so?

```
CREATE EVENT del_30sec
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 30 SECOND
COMMENT 'Deletes data every 30 seconds'
DO
DELETE FROM <table> WHERE id="xyz";
```

Comment: It might do this already. Have you checked?

Comment: You will have to use the `starts`-setting, see e.g. [Mysql Events Execution Start time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685257/mysql-events-execution-start-time).

Comment: ok it was a missunderstanding about the start time